# Cannot display view controller via didSelectRow tableView method

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am building a meme generator app. I have a meme generator screen that is called by a nav bar button item inside of either tab bar view controller screens. The first tab bar screen presents saved memes in a table view and the second presents saved memes in a collection view. I am attempting to add a details view controller that shows the saved meme when the user taps the row on the table view controller and currently, my app is crashing on the touch event.

Here is the code from my table view controller:

```
import UIKit

class TableViewMemesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var memes: [Meme]! {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        memes = appDelegate.memes
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return memes.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        let meme = memes[indexPath.row]
        cell?.imageView?.image = meme.memedImage
        cell?.textLabel?.text = meme.topText
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let meme = memes[indexPath.row]
        let detailController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsCollectionViewCell") as! DetailsCollectionViewCell
        detailController.detailsImageView.image = meme.memedImage
        present(detailController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Here is the code from my details view controller:

```
import UIKit

class DetailsCollectionViewCell: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var detailsImageView: UIImageView!


}
```

When I tap on the corresponding row, the app crashes and I receive the following error:

```
2018-01-01 14:58:28.569113-0600 memeGenerator[6120:358774] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-01-01 14:58:28.570701-0600 memeGenerator[6120:358774] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-01-01 14:58:32.459620-0600 memeGenerator[6120:358774] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/angelatuzson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DEDF59A7-71B0-4C2B-85AF-8A877A7426C2/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2018-01-01 14:58:32.460974-0600 memeGenerator[6120:358774] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2018-01-01 14:58:35.347192-0600 memeGenerator[6120:358824] [discovery] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}
1
2018-01-01 14:58:40.220065-0600 memeGenerator[6120:358774] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x600000469600>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'DetailsCollectionViewCell''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d91f12b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109518f41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   UIKit                               0x000000010ade90d7 -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] + 0
    3   memeGenerator                       0x0000000108bd89fe _T013memeGenerator014TableViewMemesD10ControllerC05tableD0ySo07UITableD0C_10Foundation9IndexPathV14didSelectRowAttF + 718
    4   memeGenerator                       0x0000000108bd903c _T013memeGenerator014TableViewMemesD10ControllerC05tableD0ySo07UITableD0C_10Foundation9IndexPathV14didSelectRowAttFTo + 92
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010a60a839 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1810
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010a60aa54 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 344
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010a4d3d59 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 318
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010a4c2bb1 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 280
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010a4f20e0 _afterCACommitHandler + 137
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d8c1c07 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d8c1b5e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d8a6124 __CFRunLoopRun + 1572
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d8a5889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001112549c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010a4c85d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    16  memeGenerator                       0x0000000108be5157 main + 55
    17  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010eabdd81 start + 1
    18  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

[Here](https://github.com/andrewTuzson/memeGenerator) is a link to the repo. I am trying to have the app display the details view controller with the saved meme image when the user taps on the corresponding row. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What's the actual issue with the code you posted?

Comment: I am not sure why the app crashes when I tap on the row. I want the app to call the details view controller.

Comment: If your app is crashing then update your question (don't post in comments) with complete details about the crash. Show the complete and exact error message. Point out the exact line of code causing the crash.

Comment: What is the exception message?  I can see a forced unwrap and a forced downcast in your `didSelect` code. Either of those could be your problem.

Comment: Adding that now. My mistake.

Comment: @Paulw11 Most likely it's accessing the `detailsImageView` outlet too soon. It's probably an error about force-unwrapping a nil optional (OK, that will be the next error after this one is fixed).

Comment: Is the class for your details view controller `DetailsCollectionViewCell`?  That sounds more like a cell class than a view controlller class. Regardless the exception message you have now posted states clearly what your problem is. There is no scene with the identifier you have specified.

Comment: @AndrewTuzson Read the error. Clearly your view controller has a different name and not `DetailsCollectionViewCell`.

Comment: Reading these errors is super new to me. They are tough to read in Xcode. Do you ever pull the errors into a different editor to help with formatting?

Comment: I updated that and I am still getting the same crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two crashes: the first is because the storyboard you are using is wrong (`DetailsCollectionViewCell` is not defined inside `self.storyboard`), the second because you are trying to set meme image inside `detailsImageView` which is not yet initialized, so you might change your `didSelectRowAt` in this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let meme = memes[indexPath.row]
    let detailController = UIStoryboard(name: "DetailsStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsCollectionViewCell") as! DetailsCollectionViewCell
    present(detailController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    detailController.detailsImageView.image = meme.memedImage
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I updated the syntax and the storyboard ID. I am still getting hit with the crash though. I updated the repo with these changes. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are using `UIStoryboard(name: "DetailsViewController")`: `DetailsViewController` is not a storyboard, is a ViewController defined inside of it. Your storyboard is called: `DetailsStoryboard`.